# Instead of running in two server ports(angular:4200 and node:3000) can we make it as one(angular+node:3000) Angular+Node+MongoDB

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment, localhost, production

1. How to deploy the localhost developed application with
   Angular+Node+MongoDB in production. Please share the steps to
   follow.
2. Instead of running in two server ports(angular:4200 and node:3000)
   can we make it as one(angular+node:3000).

Any other suggestions appreciated.Thank you...

Comment: Angular js a front-end application, why should it bind to a port?

Comment: development env, I'm using with default template installation.

Answer (score 0):

[Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) can do that for you.

You create three container for each part of your application:

- Angular
- Node
- MongoDB

Containers can be viewed as lightweight virtual machine.

Then you can use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to run them as a service. It will link all the containers together and you can choose which one to expose to the outside. In you case that will be the Angular service on port 4200 (you can expose it on 3000 but it would be confusing since it is the port Node is using).

If you also want your Node API to be available outside your application, you can expose it on port 3000.

Check this [detailled article](https://www.edureka.co/blog/docker-compose-containerizing-mean-stack-application/) that explain how to use docker-compose with Angular/Node/mongoDB.